# Количество товаров в категории minishop2

Tags: modx, minishop2

Как ограничить количество товаров в категории minishop2?

К примеру:

В категории должно быть 50 товаров, при добавлении нового, самый старый уже не показывается.

Или:

В категории 5 страниц по 10 товаров и сколько бы не добавлять, всегда оставалось 5 по 10 с последними добавленными товарами.

Answer (score 0):

Есть параметр limit, вот тут и нужно указывать количество отображаемых товаров на странице, а после что б работала пагинация.
Соответственно есть еще и сортировка sortdir.

Вот собственно и все

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете сниппет msProducts для вывода товаров, то достаточно изменить значение параметра `limit` https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/minishop2/snippetyi/msproducts